# Javascript object becomes undefined in a for loop

Tags: javascript

When I am trying to add the usersData object to the filter idToName inside the for loop, it suddenly becomes undefined. Shouldn't the usersData get the value before the for loop runs? How should I fix it?

```
  Project.getProjects()
  .success(function(data) {
    vm.projects = data;
    var projectLength = vm.projects.length;

    // Get usersData
    User.allUsers()
    .success(function(data) {
      usersData = data;
      console.log(usersData); // It prints the object
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < projectLength; i++){
      console.log(usersData); // It prints undefined
      vm.projects[i].assigneeID = $filter('idToName')(vm.projects[i].assigneeID, usersData);
    }
  })
```

Comment: The success callback has not executed when the for loop runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be due to async calls. Try updating your code to following

```
// Get usersData
    User.allUsers()
    .success(function(data) {
      usersData = data;
      console.log(usersData); // It prints the object
      for (var i = 0; i < projectLength; i++){
          console.log(usersData); // It prints undefined
           vm.projects[i].assigneeID = $filter('idToName')(vm.projects[i].assigneeID, usersData);
      } 
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `for` loop to inside the callback for the `User.allUsers` call. You're consuming the `usersData` before object is returned!

Comment: 'Consuming the object' is a pretty inaccurate and confusing thing to say about a variable scope issue.

Comment: It's more of a (deterministic) race condition than a scoping issue. As far as we can tell, `usersData` is scoped globally.